# How to do transaction on concurrency situation in nestjs, prisma

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, nestjs, prisma

While on the transaction in parallel situation, prisma throw error like that message
so i wanna know why it error occured, and how to resolove it,

ERROR MESSAGE

```
[Nest] 43187  - 2024. 03. 17. 오후 4:14:56   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Transaction API error: Transaction not found. Transaction ID is invalid, refers to an old closed transaction Prisma doesn't have information about anymore, or was obtained before disconnecting.
PrismaClientKnownRequestError: Transaction API error: Transaction not found. Transaction ID is invalid, refers to an old closed transaction Prisma doesn't have information about anymore, or was obtained before disconnecting.
    at xt.transaction (/src/node_modules/.pnpm/@prisma+client@5.11.0(prisma@5.11.0)/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:111:12322)
    at Proxy._transactionWithCallback (/src/node_modules/.pnpm/@prisma+client@5.11.0(prisma@5.11.0)/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:127:9568)
    at AccountService.recharge (/src/src/account/charge.service.ts:34:5)
    at /src/node_modules/.pnpm/@nestjs+core@10.3.3(@nestjs+common@10.3.3)(@nestjs+platform-express@10.3.3)(reflect-metadata@0.2.1)(rxjs@7.8.1)/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:46:28
    at /src/node_modules/.pnpm/@nestjs+core@10.3.3(@nestjs+common@10.3.3)(@nestjs+platform-express@10.3.3)(reflect-metadata@0.2.1)(rxjs@7.8.1)/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:17
```

TEST CODE

```
const willChargeAmount = Array.from({ length: 20 }, () =>
  randomIntByRange(1000, 5000),
);

console.log(willChargeAmount);

console.log('-------------------------------------------------');
const responses = await Promise.all(
  willChargeAmount.map((amount) =>
    request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post(`/users/${foundUser?.user_id}/recharge`)
      .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${jwt}`)
      .send({ amount }),
  ),
);
console.log('-------------------------------------------------');
```

charge.service.ts

```
public async recharge(rechargeRequest: chrageDatas) {
  await this.accountRepository.recharge(rechargeRequest);
}
```

accountRepository.ts

```
public async recharge(
  rechargeRequest: chrageDatas,
) {
  return this.prismaService.prisma.$transaction(async (tx) => {
    const amounts = await tx.accounts.findMany({
      where: {
        AND: [
          { user_id: rechargeRequest.user.userId }
        ],
      },
    });

    const points = amounts.filter(
      (amount) => amount.type === PERMANENT,
    );

    if (points.length >= 1) {
      return tx.accounts.update({
        where: {
          account_id: points[0].account_id,
        },
        data: {
          amount: rechargeRequest.amount,
        },
      });
    }
    return tx.accounts.create({
      data: {
        users: {
          connect: {
            user_id: rechargeRequest.user.userId,
          },
        },
        type: PERMANENT,
        amount: rechargeRequest.amount,
      },
    });
  });
}
```

prisma.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class PrismaService implements OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy {
  public prisma: PrismaClient;


  public async onModuleDestroy() {
    await this.prisma.$disconnect();
  }

  public async onModuleInit() {
    this.prisma = new PrismaClient();

    await this.prisma.$connect();
  }
}
```

and prisma connected on booting and destory at "OnModuleDestroy"

i'm expection nothing error occured, and finish transcation successfully